# large SQL query getting real slow when filtering date, embedded in PHP

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

I am no **SQL** pro at all and this query took a lot from me. It all does work fine until it comes to **date-filtering**.
This query  is embedded in PHP Code. 
Firstly the user is able to set filters, like the user-filter area-filter. After pressing the filter button the defined SQL statement is loaded. Everything works pretty nicely when filtering users, status, and area. It is a bit slow, but bearable. **But when I use the date filter the whole statements takes nearly one minute to load, which is not cool at all.** I read a lot about SQL date filtering but nothing really helped (or I didn't understand). Is there a noob mistake I made? Like I said, I write SQL statements once in a while, but I have no profound knowledge of it.

```
$userstatement = "AND BenutzerId ='".$benutzerfilter."'"; // asd1134
$statusstatement = "AND s.Name ='".$statusfilter."'"; // ie "deleted"
$areastatement = "AND b.Name ='".$areafilter."'"; // ie "Video"
$selected_date = $datefilter_from; // ie '2018-01-01'
$monthfilter = 2; //possible values 1-24


$bigQuery = "SELECT * FROM (  SELECT r.id, r.BenutzerId as BenutzerId,  equi.Bezeichnung, equi.VerleihprioritaetId, r.EquipmentId as eId, r.res_von, r.res_bis, equi.TypId, t.Name as TypName, r.Kommentar_user, s.Name as Status, b.Name as Bereich, b.Id as BereichId, btzr.Vorname, btzr.Nachname, IF(pe.Id,true,false) AS inPaket,
                 (  SELECT  max(gr.verleihstufe) as Verleihstufe
                    FROM benutzeringruppe as bengr
                    left join benutzergruppen as gr
                     on bengr.gruppenid = gr.Id
                    left join benutzer as ben
                     on bengr.benutzerid = ben.Id
                    where ben.id = r.BenutzerId 
                    AND gr.bereichid = b.Id
                    group by ben.id  ) as Verleihstufe,
                 (  SELECT true 
                    FROM benutzeringruppe as bg 
                    LEFT JOIN direktberechtigung as d2 
                     ON bg.gruppenid = d2.gruppenid 
                    WHERE bg.benutzerid = r.BenutzerId 
                    AND d2.equipmentid = r.EquipmentId LIMIT 1) 
                    as EquipmentDirektberechtigt
                   FROM reservierung as r
                   left join equipment as equi
                    on r.EquipmentId = equi.Id
                   left join typ as t 
                    on equi.TypId = t.Id
                   left join status as s
                    on r.StatusId = s.Id
                   left join bereich as b 
                    on equi.BereichId = b.Id
                   left join direktberechtigung as d
                    on r.EquipmentId = d.equipmentid
                   left join paketEq as pe
                    on r.EquipmentId = pe.EquipmentId 
                   left join benutzer as btzr
                    on r.BenutzerId = btzr.Id
                   Where r.res_von > '$selected_date' 
                   AND r.res_von < DATE_ADD
                   ('" .$selected_date. "', INTERVAL ".$monatsfilter." MONTH)
                   ".$statusstatement." ".$userstatement." ".$areastatement.")
            AS Big
            Order by Big.res_von DESC";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using DATE_ADD will prevent query caching, so you might get better performance by calculating the date in PHP first with something like:

```
$startdate = new DateTime($selected_date);
$startdate->modify('-' . $monthfilter . ' month');
```

and then do :

```
AND r.res_von < '" . $startdate->format('Y-m-d') . "'
```

Comment: thanks chris, this did indeed make the query faster. it is still around 20 seconds. do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: You have a lot of joins in your query. I would suggest ensuring that you have indexes in place. Try running your query with 'EXPLAIN ' in front of it - the output will tell you which indexes are being used and give clues as to how they can be improved.

Also, you are using sub-queries. If you can re-write it without them it may be faster.